# Confusion about energy transport in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electric-fields

I have some confusions about how to imagine energy flow in a circuit. Imagine for example just a simple circuit with a battery, two wires and a light bulb.

According to classical Electrodynamics the energy is transported by the electromagnetic field outside the wires to the light bulb and we can describe the direction of energy flux by the Poynting vector.
So far, so good…

But I have a few questions at this point:

1.) A few sources emphasize that it is NOT the electrons that transport the energy to the light bulb but the EM waves. But when the EM waves hit the light bulb, the light and thermical energy is created by fast moving electrons or am I wrong? So it is not right say that electrons transport energy but it should be right to say that EM waves give the energy to the electrons and they vibrate and this kinetic energy is used?

2.) In addition to the first question: I am always wondering how does the field know where the light bulb is? The obvious answer would be: it doesn’t. But with that logic, the energy from the EM field should be at every point of the wire. Is that correct?
I am confused because pictures like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9K80.png) only show the energy transport directly to the light bulb but shouldn’t the energy be transported everywhere?

I hope someone can clear up my confusion :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave "knows" where the bulb is because the EM field is directed by the wires to the bulb: The H-field surrounds the wire, while the E-field is between the wires.

Experimentally, there is no way to prove that the "field" lights up the bulb and not the motion of the electrons. The reason behind this explanation is not this simple example of a bulb connected to a battery but that this example serves as a didactic introduction to energy transfer between antennas that are not connected by anything "material", as in a radio or cell phone communicating with a tower.

In those cases there is no *other* rational explanation but that EM wave energy travels via the field that Faraday and Maxwell envisioned. Between this battery to bulb example and of the radios there is the intermediate case of a transmission line formed by pairs of long wires, long relative to wavelength (Lecher wire), where the bulb lights up before any individual electrons could travel the distance, but even in that case one could claim that the *current* lights up the bulb not the field. This is the case because where there is no current there is no H-field to surround the wire, and where is no charge accumulation neither there is E-field. In other words, as long as we have the wires we have both currents/charges and H/E fields, it is your preference to say which lights up the bulb.

Comment: But the bulb is lightened up by fast moving electrons which cause thermal energy and therefore light, right? But doesn’t that contradict the fact that all the electrons in the wire have a constant drift velocity??

Comment: It is not true that "all the electrons in the wire have a constant drift velocity" its different in the bulb or thin wire from the connecting thick wire.

Comment: Okay thanks! :)

Comment: But I still don’t understand why all the energy goes to the light bulb? I mean the wire is also a resistor, it should absorb energy as well. So the pointing vector should not only be going into the light bulb but to all points of the wire, right? (In the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9K80.png)

Comment: You should distinguish between thermal velocity, which random in all directions, and drift velocity along the wire that is the result of the bias voltage and collisions between the electron and the ions in the metal. This is an analogous to the distinction between thermal velocity of the gas molecules and their average speed as they are moved together by an external piston. Along the wire the electrons move very slowly, only at a few mm/sec, their drift speed is not faster in the bulb.

Comment: But I still don’t understand why all the energy goes to the light bulb? I mean the wire is also a resistor, it should absorb energy as well. So the pointing vector should not only be going into the light bulb but to all points of the wire, right? (In the picture i.stack.imgur.com/f9K80.png)

Comment: Not all energy goes to the bulb, this is especially evident in the case of a long transmission line. But even in the example in your question, assuming zero wire resistance, the delivered power (energy) depends on the internal resistance (impedance) of the source and how is that related to the impedance of the bulb. If the wire has internal resistance then it also dissipates energy, which the simple explanations usually ignore. Again, do not forget the explanation is a didactic introduction to much more complicated wave phenomena and it serves only to get you accustomed to them..

Comment: So it is correct to say that the electrons receive the energy from the EM field and it gets converted into kinetic energy by the electrons in random movements. And this is the energy that is used for example to light the bulb?

Comment: Yes, that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some confusions about how to imagine energy flow in a circuit. Imagine for example just a simple circuit with a battery, two wires and a light bulb.

> According to classical Electrodynamics the energy is transported by the electromagnetic field outside the wires to the light bulb and we can describe the direction of energy flux by the Poynting vector.

The wires are a long and narrow capacitor. The battery charges the capacitor. The energy is stored outside of the wires as electric field energy. The electric field is formed by the small electric fields of electrons inside the wires.

The bulb is discharging the long capacitor.

How does battery know to stop charging the long capacitor when the bulb stops discharging the capacitor? Well, when the voltage of the capacitor equals the voltage of the battery, then the charging stops. It works like that with normal capacitors, so it works like that with long capacitors too, right?